How to load the tokenizer locally from Unbabel/COMET
I am trying to use COMET in a place where it cannot download its own models. It seems to load wmt22-comet-da model as far as I can tell, but it seems not to recognize my local xlm-roberta-large instance (which is placed in /opt/huggingface/xlm-roberta-large, and /opt/huggingface is the HF_HOME).
Question: can I specify local path for the xlm-roberta tokenizer so that COMET works without downloading anything itself?
from comet import load_from_checkpoint

model = load_from_checkpoint("third_party/Unbabel/wmt22-comet-da/checkpoints/model.ckpt")
data = [
    {
        "src": "这是个句子。",
        "mt": "This is a sentence.",
        "ref": "It is a sentence."
    },
    {
        "src": "这是另一个句子。",
        "mt": "This is another sentence.",
        "ref": "It is another sentence."
    }
]
model_output = model.predict(data, batch_size=8)

The above program crashes with these exceptions:
/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: '/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/image.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c1017RegisterOperatorsD1Ev'If you don't plan on using image functionality from `torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg` or `libpng` installed before building `torchvision` from source?
  warn(
Lightning automatically upgraded your loaded checkpoint from v1.8.3.post1 to v2.4.0. To apply the upgrade to your files permanently, run `python -m pytorch_lightning.utilities.upgrade_checkpoint third_party/Unbabel/wmt22-comet-da/checkpoints/model.ckpt`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 712, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1014, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 374, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 925, in _tunnel
    raise OSError(f"Tunnel connection failed: {code} {message.strip()}")
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 504 Gateway Time-out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 801, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 594, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /xlm-roberta-large/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 504 Gateway Time-out')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr1/MIR-DEV/mtmc/comet_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    model = load_from_checkpoint("third_party/Unbabel/wmt22-comet-da/checkpoints/model.ckpt")
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/comet/models/__init__.py", line 88, in load_from_checkpoint
    model = model_class.load_from_checkpoint(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/model_helpers.py", line 125, in wrapper
    return self.method(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1582, in load_from_checkpoint
    loaded = _load_from_checkpoint(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py", line 91, in _load_from_checkpoint
    model = _load_state(cls, checkpoint, strict=strict, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py", line 165, in _load_state
    obj = instantiator(cls, _cls_kwargs) if instantiator else cls(**_cls_kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/comet/models/regression/regression_metric.py", line 98, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/comet/models/base.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.encoder = str2encoder[self.hparams.encoder_model].from_pretrained(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/comet/encoders/xlmr.py", line 78, in from_pretrained
    return XLMREncoder(pretrained_model, load_pretrained_weights)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/comet/encoders/xlmr.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2190, in from_pretrained
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 402, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_deprecation.py", line 101, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 114, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1232, in hf_hub_download
    return _hf_hub_download_to_cache_dir(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1295, in _hf_hub_download_to_cache_dir
    (url_to_download, etag, commit_hash, expected_size, head_call_error) = _get_metadata_or_catch_error(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1746, in _get_metadata_or_catch_error
    metadata = get_hf_file_metadata(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 114, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1666, in get_hf_file_metadata
    r = _request_wrapper(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 364, in _request_wrapper
    response = _request_wrapper(
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 387, in _request_wrapper
    response = get_session().request(method=method, url=url, **params)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_http.py", line 93, in send
    return super().send(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 694, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /xlm-roberta-large/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 504 Gateway Time-out')))"), '(Request ID: ###############)')

Library versions:

unbabel-comet==2.2.2
torch==2.5.0
transformers==4.44.2


turn on the reload,
model = load_from_checkpoint("third_party/Unbabel/wmt22-comet-da/checkpoints/model.ckpt", reload_params=True)

and override the "xlm path" in the local comet hparams.yaml:
it should be "third_party/Unbabel/wmt22-comet-da/hparams.yaml" considering your proposed local comet ckpt:
pretrained_model: "local/path/to/infoxlm-large"

(sorry I misspelled the pretained model, now it'd fixed)

I actually tried doing that, but it still attempted to download the model for some reason :(

@MrVocabulary Did you notice what it was downloading? the vocabulary? or model parameters?

My versions: torch==2.3.1, transformers==4.46.1, unbabel-comet==2.2.2

As far as I can tell, it was trying to download tokenizer_config.json, but it was already present in directory specified as HF_HOME in my env, along with all other necessary files. This one is mentioned in the error I quoted, anyways.

@MrVocabulary that would be the tokenizer from infoxlm-large, I fixed this by specifying the "pretrained_model" the wmt22-comet-da/hparams.yaml.
